# Integrate Gmail api with Google app maker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm creating a google app using app maker. I want to integrate the Gmail API with the application. I went through it's [guideline](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/), but couldn't able to find any useful resource for my use case. 
According to the guideline, [google app script](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/apps-script) are supporting this, but I don't' know if it is possible to integrate the that it to the Google App Maker application.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I have done a bit of research and found that there's an inbuilt object called **GmailApp** which could be access via a server script. There are number of functions related to that. What I particularly looking for is to get/read email thread for the given subject and open it in a separate browser window, so the user will be able to interact with it (read the thread, reply..etc.)

Comment: In the "Sample and templates" section of google app maker tou can find "Email PDF". Maybe it could help you.
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/email-pdf/

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda, thanks. I've put an update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to integrate the Gmail API by going to 
**APP SETTINGS** -> **Advanced services** and click on **ADD SERVICE**.

From there we could select Gmail API from the available services. As shown in the screen capture below.

[image]